# Is this type of novel permissioble to read?

Tags: fiqh, sharia, image, cartoon

Hello is the fiction novel unordinary(webtoon) permissible to read?

This is a story based on ability a person has and has nothing to do with magic in that case will it be permissible to read?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at drawings, paintings, pictures is not prohibited in Islam and in principle.

You're allowed to read any book even if it includes pictures, paintings, drawings, of any sort as long as it is free from Islamic prohibitions such as pornography for example.

The mere presence of cartoon/comic characters and living beings in them does not prevent the permissibility of reading them.

Source:

- [Reading Comic Books that Have Drawn Cartoon Characters](https://islamweb.net/en/fatwa/450568/reading-comic-books-that-have-drawn-cartoon-characters)

Answer (score -1):

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

If the book has pictures that are in full form (human form or animal) then do not read. If however they are half drawn like only the head is showing or head plus shoulders are showing (like half the body) then it will be okay. Or if they are creatures that are not real in the essence of any of ALLAAH creation (humans, jinns, angels, animals).

You can search for more information regarding picture makers. However I can cite to you some narrations that prohibit drawing and even having them.

> Narrated Abu Hurairah:
> that the Messenger of ALLAAH (ﷺ) said: "Jibra'il came to me and said: "Indeed I had come to you last night, and nothing prevented me from entering upon you at the house you were in, except that there were images of men at the door of the house, and there was a curtain screen with imagines on it, and there was a dog in the house. So go and sever the head of the image that is at the door so that it will become like a tree stump, and go and cut the screen and make two throw-cushions to be sat upon, and go and expel the dog." So the Messenger of ALLAAH (ﷺ) did so, and the dog was a puppy belonging to Al-Husain or Al-Hasan which was under his belongings, so he ordered him to expel it.

> Narrated `Aisha:
> The Prophet (ﷺ) entered upon me while there was a curtain having pictures (of animals) in the house. His face got red with anger, and then he got hold of the curtain and tore it into pieces. The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Such people as paint these pictures will receive the severest punishment on the Day of Resurrection ." (Bukhari in the chapter of Good Manners and Form)

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "The painter of these pictures will be punished on the Day of Resurrection, and it will be said to them, Make alive what you have created.' " (Bukhari in the chapter of  Oneness, Uniqueness of Allah (Tawheed)

Comment: -1 These hadiths are generally directed towards the "haram to DRAW" argument even though a sizable amount of Islamic scholarship would say it's Makrooh or mubah to draw such as the Malikis. But it's NOT haram to READ a picture book or look at pictures, paintings, and drawings. 

You should cite scholarly sources that would better strengthen your argument.

So this answer is misleading and not representative of Islam's actual stance or at least its differing opinions.

Comment: Can you tell me how much awrah should be allowed to look (men/woman) in manga?

Comment: @YoMango As Salaamu 3laykum, I think these hadiths are for sure for the drawings but not only drawings. As with the hadith I mentioned about the curtains. So they didn't draw it but they were also using the drawings as curtains. So these hadiths are clear for both the drawing person and the one who uses their drawings or purchases them. And Islam's stance is always based on what the Quran and ahadith states.

Comment: @Khan, I think this site has all the details: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/72915/ruling-on-drawing-animate-beings-without-showing-the-facial-features


With regards to looking at the opposite gender we should not be looking at the opposite gender whether picture or not. Now I will say that if there is no desire then it is permissible.  https://islamqa.info/en/answers/49038/ruling-on-women-looking-at-men

Comment: @Ahmed, they are regard to woman looking at the man(not man looking at woman), what I am asking about is how much awrah of a manga/anime character(woman)be allowed to look? Take a mini skirt for example

Comment: @Khan https://islamqa.info/en/answers/82994/what-is-a-womans-awrah and https://islamqa.info/en/answers/171584/what-is-the-awrah-of-a-man

I would read these two sites above. Furthermore, you can take those definitions from the two sites and apply it any medium (paper, clay, metal, electronically, etc.) So it doesn't matter the medium its on whether drawn, sculpted, photographed. The ruling will still apply. I hope this helps. If it doesn't please reply back below with a new comment.